# Getting error Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know why m i getting this error

My html code:-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/8.2.2/firebase-app.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    
   
  </head>

<body onload="Initialize_Firebase()">
  <input type="text/submit/hidden/button/image" id="Name" value="" />
  <input type="text/submit/hidden/button/image" id="Password" value="" />
  <button type="submit" id='button' onclick="reading_data()">enter</button>
  
  
  
  
  <script src="Database.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Js-

```
function Initialize_Firebase(){
  
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "**MY API-KEY**",
    authDomain: "******.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "*******.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "*******",
    storageBucket: "*******.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "********",
    appId: "*********",
    measurementId: "**********"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
database= firebase.database();
  
}
```

Error log--

**Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function
1/12/2021, 5:18:00 PM
/Database.js:15:20**

---

I have even copied and pasted some scripts from firebase docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load this script for Firebase Database. may be this will solve your problem

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.